# Wierd result on Martingales using Law of total expectation.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_{i}\}$ be a martingale.

Then $X_{n-1}=E(X_{n}\mid X_{1}, \ldots ,X_{n-1})=E(E(X_{n}\mid X_{1}, \ldots X_{n-1}) \mid X_{1}, \ldots ,X_{n-2})=X_{n-2}$

by using first law a total expectation and then that $\{X_{i}\}$  is a martingale. But this cant be right? Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equality is wrong. You're replacing an $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n-1})$-measurable random variable on the left with its conditional expectation with respect to $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n-2})$.

There's no reason for that not to change the random variable.

Comment: So $E(E(X \mid Y)))=EX$ does not hold in this setting? This should hold for all r.v's $Y$ right?

Comment: @user21312 That fact definitely is (almost always) true. But what you have on the left of your equation is $E(X_n | X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n-1})$, not $E(E(X_n | X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{n-1}))$, so it doesn't apply.

Comment: I realized that!

Answer (score 0):

Law of total expectation say this:
$E(X)=E(E(X|\sigma (Y)))$ if $X$ and $Y$ are defined ont the same probability space.

You, you used an other property:
[image: propertyProba]
link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_probability
And you make a mistake using it. Because this equality is false: $E(X_{n+1}|\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_n))=E(E(X_{n+1}|\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_n))|\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1}))$ as $\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_n))\nsubseteq \sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1})$
It's the opposite that is correct( $\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)) \supseteq  \sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1})$ ), so you can't use this property in this case.